# Using divs to define CSS properties

Tags: css

I'm trying to separate the CSS properties of two tables depending which DIV they lie in.  If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/tpXKT/ you will see that the table in "resultA" is using the TD property defined for "resultB".

I understand that this has been applied due to the "cascade" of properties, but why has it been included if I've used the #resultB selector?  Or is this not valid?

For Stack's happiness:

```
#resultA table {border-collapse: collapse}
#resultA table th, td {border: 1px solid black}
#resultA table td {background-color: blue}

#resultB table {border-collapse: collapse}
#resultB table th, td {border: 5px solid black}
#resultB table td {background-color: red}

<div id="resultA">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11.5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you define `td` by itself twice. That is, the selector `#resultB table th` ends there, and when you use the comma to include the `td` you're just defining `td` as a standalone element. You would need to do:
`#resultA table th, #resultA table td` and `#resultA table th, #resultA table td` to get distinct styles for each of those.

Comment: Thanks Justin, that's my mistake; I thought it would join the selectors.  Is there any way to have a th & td?

Comment: You can add them like j08691 and I described above. The second `#resultA table td {background-color: red;}` will only override similar styles. So the styles you define for the border will still apply to both the `th` and the `td`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: ah yes, i see now.  thanks.  i'll set to answered when i can.

Answer (score 2):

A comma in CSS separates the selectors and doesn't keep any relation between them. So since `#resultB table th, td` comes after `#resultA table th, td` the `td` rule is being overwritten by the last rule since it comes last. You probably want to do this instead:

```
#resultB table th, #resultB table td {border: 5px solid black}
```

By specifically defining the path of your rule, you ensure that it won't be applied to other elements.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tpXKT/1/)**